# When applying ListView's custom list item with a root ViewGroup implementing Checkable, can't the selected item's color be changed?

Tags: android, android-layout

I already successfully changed the *color* of a selected *custom list item*, whose root `ViewGroup` doesn't implement `Checkable`, from orange to system_blue by assigning its attr background with a `selector.xml`:

```
<selector>  
    <item android:state_pressed="true" 
        android:drawable="@color/system_blue"/>
    <item android:state_checked="true"
        android:drawable="@color/system_blue"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/> 
</selector>
```

Even the `state_checked` case is defined, but the state of the selected list item will not be maintained after the finger left the selected item.

Now the custom list item's root `ViewGroup implements Checkable`, for I need to maintain the status of the selected list item. And Interface `Checkable`'s the member function `setChecked()` is implemented as following:

```
public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
    mChecked = checked;
    setBackgroundDrawable(checked ? new ColorDrawable(
    getResources().getColor(R.color.system_blue)) : null);
}
```

Now the selected item's color can be maintained to system_blue, after the finger left the select item. Nevertheless when pressing the item, the color is first changed to default orange instead of system_blue. My android device has a default orange color. Any ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try handling the checking by yourself, set the choice mode of the listView to [CHOICE_MODE_NONE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#CHOICE_MODE_NONE).

And handle the checked state of the items in onItemClickListener of the listView. So you have full control over the background and the state.

Comment: It sounds doable. But could you give me some hints or examples about how to implement changing item's color under both selecting and selected cases via **onItemClickListener**. Thank you in advance.

Comment: No, I found out that OnItemClickListener's callback function onItemClick() will then be invoked after the finger left the select item. But I want to customize something like "onItemBeingClicked()" to set an arbitrary color when selecing an item. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Add an OnTouchListener to your view and with the MotionEvent you have full control over how the user interacts with the view.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I will upvote your answer as long as I've got sufficient reputation score.

Answer (score 0):

Check this example that I make today to do exacttly this:

[Code on Github](https://github.com/sabadow/ListMultiSelect-Android-Example/)

**Edit**

To make the item color changed while pressing, need to add a new item for the pressed state, like this:

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_bg_hover" 
    android:state_pressed="true"/>
```

Comment: The example does change the color after an item is selected, but doesn't change color when selecting an item. I want to set both selecting and selected item's color to whatever color I want. Sorry I didn't explain the question clearly for the sake of bad English.

Comment: Thank you for the concise example.

Comment: But I already added **state_pressed** in seletor. The problem is that the color defined for the **state_pressed** will be ignored, as long as root **ViewGroup** of the list item, i.e. the class **MyLinear**, implements Checkable. Thank you in advance!

Comment: But in my case it's actually **CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE**, and as long as the root **ViewGroup** of the list item implements **Checkable**, the color for **state_pressed** defined in the selecor will be ignored. Could you give me some insights about that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If working on HoneyComb and above just add

```
?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator
```

as the background of the parent view. Its an easy fix :)